# Shift scroll doesn't horizontally scroll with any external mouse

Tags: mouse, macos

I used to use Shift+scroll to scroll horizontally in the past. However, when I tried this on my MacBook running macOS Catalina, it didn't seem to work. I tried this with multiple external mouses—the result is only a horizontal scroll, irrespective of whether the shift key is held down. I tried this in Safari as well as some other apps.

I did some quick research, and it seems as shift-scrolling should scroll horizontally, as seen [here](https://www.alvinpoh.com/how-to-scroll-horizontally-left-and-right-in-mac-os/), [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040217231336496), and [here](https://osxdaily.com/2012/01/26/scroll-horizontally-with-a-mouse-wheel-by-holding-shift/).

Could this possibly have been a removed feature in Catalina? If so, what are my options for getting it back?

Comment: Did you mean "the result is only a *vertical* scroll"?

Comment: That is indeed what I meant

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue was that I was using [Mos](https://mos.caldis.me) to enable smooth scrolling on my Mac.

However, it removes the ability to scroll horizontally using the shift key by default. To reenable this behavior, go to Mos Settings > Advanced and then select "Shift" as the horizontal scrolling key. That should do it!

Comment: Thank you! I was so confused why it wasn't working anymore.

Comment: I have Mos and have the same issue, however this option does not appear in Settings for me in the latest version

Comment: @LeaveTheCapital I have the latest version of MOS (I think) and the setting you need is Mos Settings > Advanced > Toggle Key. I have just set mine to shift and finally got horizontal scrolling on the mouse wheel.

Comment: @Bryan Thank you so much, it worked!